# Razor get value of input HTML bounded by foreach

Tags: c#, html, razor, input

I have one following table html, the data of rows in the table is looped by foreach.

Can I use Razor to get the value of each row into a List or an array in C#?

My C# code Razor (I tried this so far)

```
 @{
           var l = new List<string>();                         
           l.Add(@<input id="updated_value2" data-bind="value:value,visible:isEditing()" />);
       }
```

Here's my table

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.mapJsons(parameters())">
            <tr class="data-hover">
                <td>
                    <strong>
                        <span data-bind="text:key" />
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td>

                    @*display label and input for dictionary<value> false DIS true APP*@
                    <input id="updated_value" data-bind="value:value,visible:isEditing()" />
                    <label id="display_value" data-bind="text:value,visible:!isEditing()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 30%">
                    Name
                </th>
                <th style="width: 30%">
                    Value
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: If you are thinking to access value of the input element which is present as string in List or Array, then it is not possible. BUT Yes, if you are planning to render the Html String which is present in list and form a table, then it is possible

Comment: @K D Yes, I would like to get the value which presents in a form of table html, and for each row in the table I have each item in the List<>

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach loop is being executed client-side (looks like a KnockoutJS binding?) rather than server-side, so any Razor code you embed in the table is only going to be called once as it's rendered by the server.  So the answer is no, you cannot populate a server-side list with this particular foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , so do you have any idea to loop through all the data in the html table and store them into a List by code behind

Comment: The data is inside a javascript object, not a server-side object, so it might not even be available to the code behind (impossible to tell from the code you've posted).  If you need the data on the server then you may need to send it via an additional web request.  Or, if you only need it on the client side, you should be able to iterate over the list using just javascript.